# Error 403 on Calling Firebase Firestore Rest API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Here the code how i am generating the accessToken for Calling API.

```
import firebaseConfig from './../firebaseConfig';
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  sessionStorage.setItem("__token", token);    // Token saved
}.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {

});
```

With that code i am getting the token in sessionStorage. 
Here's the snippet how i am using firebase Rest API.

```
var URL = https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/qtbt-a8bf8/databases/(default)/documents/users/[USER_ID]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
var token = sessionStorage.getItem("__token");
const config = {
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` , Accept: 'application/json'}
};

axios.get(URL, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

In the axios call, i am getting Error 403.
Response:

```
code: 403
message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

Comment: Most of the time you find permission problems to the firestore db is due to the security rules you specify.
Check the rules and make sure that you allow and deny appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your missing the api-key in the call. apikey and token should both be in the headers.

```
var token = sessionStorage.getItem("__token");// verify your token is correct. 
var headers = {'x-api-key' : 'key valu goes here', 'authorization': ${token} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The security rule is slightly different when using an IdToken rather than an OAuth token.

Instead of using:

if request.auth.uid == resource.id;

I use:

if request.auth.token.email == resource.id;

I'm matching the token's owner email to the document id, which also happens to be the owner's email.

You can also access the user's child documents using something like:

request.auth.token.email == resource.data.ownerEa;

In that case, the document(s) being matched must have an attribute ownerEa that has value == user's email.

Very annoying documentation isn't it.

Hope that helps...